# Heatmap on a map in Python

Tags: python, visualization, geospatial

[Mode Analytics](https://community.modeanalytics.com/gallery/geographic-heat-map/) has a nice heatmap feature, but it is not conducive to comparing maps (only one per report).

[image]

What they do allow is data to be pulled easily into a wrapped python notebook.  And then any image in python can easily be added to a report.

So my question is: how do I recreate a heatmap on an actual map in Python?  I've checked out follium and plotly, but neither seem to have similar functionality.

Comment: Folium has a [plugin for heat maps](https://github.com/python-visualization/folium/blob/master/folium/plugins/heat_map.py). [Here is an example](http://qingkaikong.blogspot.com/2016/06/using-folium-3-heatmap.html).

Comment: Thanks @Emre that's exactly what I needed.  Sadly Mode doesn't support folium yet, but I'll bug their customer service and see if they'll load it.

Comment: Another good library for this is `gmplot` which also let's you export the map as a standalone html file. [Here](https://eatsleepdata.com/data-viz/how-to-generate-a-geographical-heatmap-with-python.html) is a tutorial on using it.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Looks like the [gmaps](https://github.com/pbugnion/gmaps) package is what you're looking for.

You can do things like this with it:

[image: gmap]